# Prevent a common event from firing twice

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am having an issue with preventing repeated clicks of the same element that can produce unwanted results. I cannot use jquery's one() because this event is attached to many elements, including children of the clicked element.

Essentially I have a div. The user may click on the div and it will make an AJAX request to load another div. The user may accidentally click the div again (as I have done often) and this will result in two AJAX requests and load two child divs. There is logic to prevent further children if the child is already found, but during the loading of the AJAX request it is possible to request it again. The same element should not be able to be clicked twice and request to AJAX requests. However multiple elements could be potentially clicked at the same time.

Each child div can also load more children using the exact same on('click') handler. What can I do to prevent repeated clicks sending multiple AJAX requests without using jquery's one() ?

THe below is just an example but this is the logic:

HTML

```
<div id = "parent" class = "button"> Click Me </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  var data = getsomedata();
  $.post(url, data, function(data){
    $('.resultDiv').after(data);
  });
});
```

PHP

```
function someData ($db, $request){
  do some database request
  echo '<div class = "child button"> I am a child table that is also clickable </div>';
}
```

Comment: Are you saying there should never be two Ajax requests at the same time, not even from clicks on separate elements? Can any single element allow multiple clicks as long as any previous processing from the first click has finished?

Comment: I will add that to the question: The same element should not be able to be clicked twice and request two AJAX requests. However multiple elements could be potentially clicked at the same time. Basically I am looking for an equivalent to the "disable, true" for a button, but for a DIV or the particular AJAX request or jquery event.

Comment: Show a loading image with the background blurred, so the user will not be able to process a second request. See this sample. Should help.    http://jsfiddle.net/jveldboom/c73MQ/2/

Comment: OK, I don't understand then why `.one()` doesn't do the job for you.

Comment: Because all of my clickable elements have the same class. Therefore if I use one() than that event is only usable once.

Comment: @user3822370 [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) - Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once ***per element*** per event type. - jQuery docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) method is exactly what you're asking for. It binds a handler for the specified event to an element, and then unbinds itself when it's done. Contrary to your statement above however, it only unbinds itself from the element which triggered it. Other elements using the handler will continue to work as expected.

```
$('.button').one('click', function(){
    var data = getsomedata();
    $.post(url, data, function(data){
        $('.resultDiv').after(data);
    });
});
```

This is essentially equivalent to the below:

```
function handler() {
    var data = getsomedata();
    $.post(url, data, function(data){
        $('.resultDiv').after(data);
    });

    $(this).off('click', '.button', handler);
});
$('.button').on('click', handler);
```

This approach will only for directly bound element handlers, not delegated ones.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me like this. May I add I am attaching the handler indirectly. IE (all divs) are loaded from an AJAX request, therefore they are not on page load. Thus I use something like $('body').on('click', 'button'.....) therefore using one() does not work for me.

Comment: @user3822370 Actually this doesn't seem to work for delegated event handlers, sorry. The handler isn't bound to the element, but it's parent.

Comment: @user3822370 Another approach would be to simply stop propagation of subsequent clicks, which might be viable depending on what your interface is like. Setting a flag as suggested by @ Victory may be clearer though. Here's an example of how to do this by stopping propagation: http://jsfiddle.net/p86yhLrb/

Answer (score 2):

One very easy to follow approach is to set a flag.

```
$('.button').on('click', function(){
   var hasBeenCliked = $(this).attr("has-been-clicked");
   if (hasBeenClicked === "yes") {
       return;
   }
   $(this).attr("has-been-clicked", "yes");

  var data = getsomedata();
  $.post(url, data, function(data){
    $('.resultDiv').after(data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the elements into an array once it's fired and if the array contains the element not fire it next time.

```
var arr = new Array();
$(".button").on("click", function(){
    if($.inArray(this, arr) === -1){
        arr.push(this);
        console.log("N= " + $(this).text());
    }
    else
        console.log("Sorry!");
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/2s3k5tk2/)